# Database structure for a questionnaire for matching on yes/no questions

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I'm developing an app that two friends can use to randomly select a video game to play with each other. Both friends fill out a questionnaire about which video games they would be interested in playing with each other, and based on the matches, after a button is clicked, I want to say "Play NAME-OF-VIDEO-GAME today at 'friends' house." Each user enters their name, before taking the questionnaire is each friend is stored in the database.

Example questions:

- Would you play let 'friend' play play call of duty at your house?
- Would you play Call of Duty with 'friend' at 'friends' house?

Each friend answers the same question.

Right now I have (your recommendation does not have to be constrained by this however):

```
Users table (id, friendId, FirstName, LastName, Email, dateCreated) 

Questions table (id, questionText)
  -questionText: "Would you play Call of Duty with 'friend' at 'friends' house?", and "Would you let 'friend'  play Call of Duty with at your house?

Answers table (id, answerText)
  -answerText would be "Play Call of Duty today at 'friends' house"

Matches table (id, userId, answerId)
  -If user 1 says they would let 'friend' play call of duty at their house, and user 2 says they would play call of duty at user 1's house, then need to store answer "Play Call of Duty at user 1's house today"
```

So imagine you and a friend were both taking this questionnaire to determine who's house to play a game at for that day...what would be the best database table layout for this?

Comment: The "best" structure (if such a concept even exists) is going to depend on a bunch of factors, which would require knowing a lot more about your app. That said, I'd look up things on Database Normalization, and go from there

Comment: Why would you need to know more about my app? The entire app is laid out right there (two people answer questions, click a button an an answer based on the answer to the questions is displayed).

Just looking for an idea of how to create the tables to store this type of relationship for the data, since each question "Would you let 'friend' play call of duty at your house?" and "Would you play call of duty at 'friend's' house?" is sort of a pair of questions, which depending on how each friend answers could result in a similar "response" (play call of duty at 'friends' house today).

Comment: If that's *literally* your entire app, why use a database? Why not just hard code those questions ans answers into the application? You could go completely nuts building a BCNF database which stores versions, and all sorts of things, but the benefit of it is going to be marginal at best if it's not being used for that purpose

Comment: The reason I asked for more info was that as I see it, this is one of three scenarios. First, your app is as simple as described here, in which case database structure isn't going to make much difference. Second, the app is for fun, and you want to learn best practices regardless of what the app actually does. Third, this is a legitimate concern for you and you need to build something solid and future proof. The first scenario the answer doesnt matter. The third scenario, i'd need more info. The second scenario you research normalization.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need the questions to be completely flexible (not following the above format at all), I'd scrap the "survey" setup, and go with something like:

Users table:
UserID, FirstName, LastName, Email, DateCreated

UserFriends table:
UserID1, UserID2, DateCreated

Games table:
GameID, GameName

UserHostingGame table (for storing people who said they would agree to hosting the game at their house):
UserHostingGameID, UserID, GameID, DateCreated

UserGameRequest table:
UserGameRequestID, UserID, UserHostingGameID, DateCreated